# Java SWT Image background color

Tags: java, image, colors, background, swt

I have a TableItem and i wish to add an image in it.
I use this code :

```
Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), 400, height);
image.setBackground(COLOR_RED); 
item.setImage(5, image);
```

The problem is the background color is never setting in the image. My goal is to get a transparent image background.

How can I do that?

Comment: `final TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the JavaDoc of [Image.setBackground](http://www.jdocs.com/swt/3.2/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/Image.html#M-setBackground%28Color%29). That method does not fill your image with red color.

Also, by setting an image to a TableItem you cannot draw anything, like text, transparently below that image. If you want to do something like that, you'll need "owner draw", see [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html) for a tutorial on that.